# How to use the GetInsertCommand method?

Tags: vb.net, insert

### i used the named method like this:

```
ds.Tables("Employees").Rows.Add(ENumTxt.Text, ENameTxt.Text,PosTxt.Text,EAgeTxt.Text,_
ESalTxt.Text, EPhonTxt.Text, EAdrsTxt.Text)
If ds.HasChanges Then
            Dim AffectedDS As DataSet = ds.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added)
            Dim ComBuilder As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            da.InsertCommand = ComBuilder.GetInsertCommand()
            da.Update(AffectedDS, "Employees")
End If
```

---

but when i check the insertcommand at run time, it looks like:

`INSERT INTO Employees Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`

where are the values i entered in the text boxes?

Comment: I have no idea of what you are talking about (except that's a wrapper of SQL, of course). I suggest you add tags at least to indicate which language you use, and perhaps which database you target, if relevant.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is low quality and abandoned by the asker.

Answer (score 2):

They are probably in the Parameters collection of the InserCommand. Look at da.InsertCommand.Parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding values to the parameters eg):

```
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@p1"].Value = // some value
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@p2"].Value = // some value
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@p3"].Value = DBNull.Value // if you need to pass a null;
```

The parameters should match the order of the database table fields.

You will also need to execute the query for an insert command:

```
adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```